# Laravel 5.4 formatting result set

Tags: mysql, json, laravel-5

Can someone help me convert this query so that my result set is in different format?

```
$sessions = new Session();
$results =  $sessions->where('session_status', $status)->where('application_period_id', (int) ApplicationPeriod::all()->last()->id)->get()->pluck('speaker_id');

$speakers = Speaker::whereIn('id', $results)
                ->with('session.audiancesession.audiances')
                ->with('session.subjectsession.subjects')
                ->with(['session' => 
                       function ($query) use($status) {
                           $query->where('session_status', '=', $status);
                }])->orderBy('last_name')->get();
```

This is requested via Ajax(axios)... Now this is how result is formatted:

```
Obj->data(array of objects)->[0]->name
                                ->address
                                ->session(array of objects)
                                       ->[0]->time
                                            ->fee
```

My issue is that my session parameter is array and there can only ever be (1) so I don't need to to be an array and I would like to have object (json) instead.

Thank you!

Comment: If you're getting an array that means you've set it up as an X-to-many relationship when it should have been an X-to-one relationship

Comment: @apokryfos I was afraid of that..I have two different scanarios where i request results. 1 -> Get all sessions for speaker (that potentially has multiple results) or 2 - get me all the sessions including speakers. (which is this one) as you can tell from the first query above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have more success if you change your client-side code to work with an array of sessions each session having its speaker, that means your original query would be like

```
$sessions = Sessions::with([
         'speaker', 'audiancesession.audiances', 'subjectsession.subjects'
])->where('application_period_id', (int) ApplicationPeriod::orderBy('id','DESC')->first())->get();
```

Note the order by -> first in the `ApplicationPeriod` makes it so you don't have to get all application periods from the database to memory.

Then your client side should handle an array of sessions.

You can transform the above slightly using to get a similar result to what you need:

```
$speakers = $sessions->map(function ($session) {
       $speaker = collect($session->speaker->toArray());
       $speaker->put('session', collect($session->toArray())->except('speaker'));
       return $speaker;
})->orderBy('last_name','DESC');
```

Though I wouldn't guarantee the result here as I've not tested it on your (complex looking) data.

Comment: yeah that is funny i just reversed it a bit and I think it will work... :) thanks we had the same idea.. I appreciate the help

Comment: This is what I did:
$sessions->where('session_status', $status)
                ->where('application_period_id', (int) ApplicationPeriod::all()->last()->id)
                ->with('speaker')
                ->with('audiancesession.audiances')
                ->with('subjectsession.subjects')
                ->get();